# How can I reuse a Dense layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a network in Tensorflow, and I want to define a function that passes it's input through a `tf.layers.dense` layer (obviously, the same one). I see the `reuse` argument, but in order to use it properly it seems I need to keep a global variable just to remember if my function was called already. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no cleaner way. The best we can do is wrap `tf.layers.dense` into our abstraction and use it as an object, hiding [variable scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope)'s backbone:

```
def my_dense(*args, **kwargs):
  scope = tf.variable_scope(None, default_name='dense').__enter__()
  def f(input):
    r = tf.layers.dense(input, *args, name=scope, **kwargs)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    return r
  return f

a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
layer = my_dense(3)
a = layer(a)
a = layer(a)

print(*[[int(a) for a in v.get_shape()] for v in tf.trainable_variables()])
# Prints: "[3, 3] [3]" (one pair of (weights and biases))
```

Comment: Wow, that's neat. Much cleaner that the mess I ended up with!

Comment: You should pass some name to `my_dense` so that it's possible to use this trick for different layers.

Answer (score 12):

I find [tf.layers.Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Dense) cleaner than the above answers. All you need is a Dense object defined beforehand. Then you can reuse it any number of times.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define Dense object which is reusable
my_dense = tf.layers.Dense(3, name="optional_name")

# Define some inputs
x1 = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], dtype=tf.float32)
x2 = tf.constant([[4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=tf.float32)

# Use the Dense layer
y1 = my_dense(x1)
y2 = my_dense(x2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    y1 = sess.run(y1)
    y2 = sess.run(y2)
    print(y1)
    print(y2)
```

In fact `tf.layers.dense` function internally constructs a Dense object and pass your input to that object. For more details, check the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L179).

Comment: Dense was added after dense, for newcomers you should consider use Dense now.

Answer (score 4):

You could construct the layer against a constant of the right size and ignore the result.

This way the variable is declared but the operation should be pruned from the the graph.

For example

```
tf.layers.dense(tf.zeros(1, 128), 3, name='my_layer')

... later
hidden = tf.layers.dense(input, 3, name='my_layer', reuse=True)
```